# Hedera Token Service - What is the difference between wipe and burn?

Tags: nft, hedera-hashgraph

Can someone clarify what the difference in behaviour is for the HTS functions `wipe()` and `burn()` and why you would use them and in what scenarios?

They seem very similar in function to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Burn()](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/tokens/burn-a-token) is used to delete tokens from `the treasury account`.

[Wipe()](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/tokens/wipe-a-token) is used to delete tokens from `a user account`.

Therefore, when you call `wipe` you need to specify the account id that you want to delete the token from but you don't need to specify the account if when you call `burn`.